# Hibernate Criteria ManyToMany selection

Tags: hibernate, criteria, entitymanager

I have two classes Student and Class in @ManyToMany relationship. I would like to select all classes in which student (id = 1) is not. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to user `MEMBER OF` and equivalent in `Critera API`. Here you have some details http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/collection.

In your case it will be something like

`cb.isMemberOf(student,c.get("students"));`

where `student` is Student entity, and `c` is query root - Class.